# Can I put the Ubuntu button on the top panel instead of the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I'm a long *nix user, anda just upgraded to oneiric and found this HUGE button in the dash. I use a netbook and I don't have much vertical space, *for me* the other position was way better. So, I was wondering, how can I revert the dash button to the top bar?

Comment: You could also try reducing the size of the icons in the Launcher. Take a look at [How can I configure Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible.

Even the new button is bigger, you save vertical space because other Places buttons (Applications and Files) of Natty are now integrated in the main Dash.

One bigger button more, two buttons less.

Comment: I'm so used to the button at the top, :/
Thinking on going back to 11.04

Comment: @MarcosRoriz You'll accustom to it fast, actually it's now more comfortable. When I upgraded to Oneiric, I also complained about it ;)