# I'm using Unity 3D but my top bar isn't translucent?

Tags: unity, 11.10

I'm using Unity 3D right now and my hardware configuration allows it, but the top bar isn't translucent as I see it in other systems, why is that? How can I make it translucent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Compiz Manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it
3. You will find the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin", where, on "Experimental", there is the option "Panel Opacity", where you can set the opacity to whatever you like.

   - [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)