# Netbook-sized Unity launcher for big screen desktops?

Tags: unity

The netbook screenshots people post have much bigger dock and launcher icons (relatively) than desktops, like eight icons fill the dock.  It'd be great to use this layout on big screens too, but various options for increasing the size (CCSM, dconf, Ubuntu Tweaks) only help a little.

Is this simply due to screen resolution? Any way to duplicate the "huge" interface for use on a 1080p TV?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the size of the launcher using **Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM)**:

Warning: CCSM is in universe and not shipped by default for a reason, it can be flaky, so be careful in there, [it can break things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it), if you find yourself with a broken window manager, see this [question to reset your configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration).

1. Install Compiz config settings manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it (in the dash, search for "compiz" or "ccsm")
3. Click on the Unity Plugin it it
4. There, on the "experimental" tab, you can adjust the Launcher icon size.

   - [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Comment: Thanks but already tried that; it increases the icon size somewhat but still not as big as on netbooks. Dconf editor has the automatic or netbook setting but nothing seems to change with either.  Any other thoughts?  Anyone have a solution for comfortable layouts on big screen TVs?

Comment: Ah, i see what you want to do. As far as I remember, checking netbook setting opens the dash as well as windows maximized and changes nothing on the launcher itself. I cant figure out whether unity launcher can be increased unlimitedly. You may want to change the screen resolution, as netbooks generally have very limited screen resolution, and i am sorry i cannot help you further.