# If there a way to configure the delay between the time the mouse moves out of the launcher and the time the launcher closes?

Tags: unity, launcher

If there a way to configure the delay between the time the mouse get out of the launcher and the time the launcher close ?

I'd like to set it to 0 !

Thanks (and sorry if the answer has already be given elsewhere). I hope my poor english makes sense.

Comment: (I'm not sure about the meaning of the picture associated with my nickname ; anyway I am not responsible for this !).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current time is set in the source to 750ms, there is no user config on this.

You could re-build & adjust this value, though hardly seems to be a change that warrants this. If doing so I'd not use a value of 0, a very low ms will give the same effect.

current location in 11.10 - /unity-4.24.0/plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherHideMachine.cpp, line 44

```
  _hide_delay_timeout_length = 750;
```

Comment: Just to add - back in 11.04 We'd do just the opposite - increase the delay so that it was easier to open 2 or more apps from the launcher before it retracted

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If there a reason for not letting the user configurate this value ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity) could help. The quick response is to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>" and write "about:config" then configure Unity (you should adjust "Edge reveal timeout"). Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that "Edge reveal timeout" is related to the delay between the time the mouse comes on the left and the time the launcher appears. This is not the delay I am intersested in.