# Taskbars/Unity are visible in the MythTV frontend even when the frontend is fullscreen

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

When the MythTV frontend is full screen, the taskbars and/or Unity is still visible. How can I hide them?

Comment: Bug in mythtv, http://code.mythtv.org/trac/ticket/9589 with unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For 11.04 and newer

Use compizconfig-settings-manager `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` from a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), then run it from the dash, just open dash and type ccsm and then goto the Unity plugin and in there you can choose panel opacity to 0.  It's the best I can suggest without disabling compiz, and therefore unity.

- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Comment: This is a [known bug](http://www.mythtv.org/pipermail/mythtv-users/2012-May/333127.html). Yet not sufficiently fixed, and AFAIK only workarounds are available.

Answer (score 3):

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Go to *Ubuntu Unity plugin* and set the option for *Hide launcher* to auto-hide. Then, go to *Workarounds* and check the box for the option *Legacy Fullscreen Support*.

This method worked for me in 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

CCSM -> Workarounds -> Legacy Full Screen Suppot.
Restart mythfrontend
fixed

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail what you're suggesting to do? In particular, you may want to explain how to install CCSM, explain (or link to information about) the risks associated with using it, and even perhaps include a screenshot showing the settings you're suggesting to change.

Answer (score 1):

#### For 10.10 and older

This is caused by compiz. Disable Compiz by going to System > Preferences > Appearance (on your Gnome taskbar). Click on the Visual Effects tab, and select none.