# How to get MythTV full screen in Unity?

Tags: 11.10, panel, fullscreen, mythbuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Taskbars/Unity are visible in the MythTV frontend even when the frontend is fullscreen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75150/taskbars-unity-are-visible-in-the-mythtv-frontend-even-when-the-frontend-is-full)

I am running MythTV in Ubuntu 11.10 but I still have the top panel showing on my TV.  How can I fix this?

A while back I found some instructions to hide to top bar:

> To get it to display without a top border:
>
> - Install CompizConfig Settings Manager
> - Navigate to Utility then Workarounds
> - Enable Legacy Fullscreen Support

But that no longer works. Any ideas?