# How to change dash transparency?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, transparency

Depending on the application that is running when I open the dash it is sometimes nearly impossible to read the icons due to the transparency of the dash background. Is there a way to change the transparency?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose the "Static blur" option the the Dash blur is set the 1st time you use the Dash per session.

So if you open the Dash over an appropriate background then that's what you'll get for the rest of the session, what you then open the Dash over won't matter

For a short time in 11.10 the "No Blur"; option used to provide a dark,solid dash, that's fallen by the wayside & no blur is pretty much worthless

Can be adjusted in the `unity plugin > experimental settings` in ccsm

If ccsm, (compizconfig-settings-manager) is installed & you wish to go directly to the unity settings then

`Alt+F2`, type in `about:config` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It can also be set from terminal, `0=no blur`, `1=static blur`, `2=active blur` (the default

Open a terminal and type the below command

```
gconftool-2 -s -t integer /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/dash_blur_experimental 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but actually the option no blu gives a much better result in my opinion.

Comment: Blurring is nothing to do with transparency, the question was about transparency

Comment: The gconftool command does not work anymore in 14.04. Can you please update it?

Comment: `The gconftool command does not work anymore in 14.04. Can you please update it? –  king_julien` -  No reason to do so. This question is 2.5 yr.s old & for 11.10. Maybe ask a new question (hint: Dash opacity is controlled by the opacity level of the 'background' color, ie. only can be adjusted when using a custom or black background color

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to manage the Dash transparency as yet, though you can change the blur. The Dash colour is affected by your wallpaper though, so you may need to change the wallpaper.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks.

Comment: The answer, though I was not hoping this.

Comment: This has already been there for more than a year. Do we have any news about changing Dash transparency?

Comment: Unfortunately no change yet.

Comment: Which file has the styling rules for Unity Dash?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-unity-on-low-end-system/) one.

Just put in your `~/.xprofile` (make new file if it doesn't exist):

```
export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE=1
```

It also disables other animations like pop-up blur etc. It works with Ubuntu 13.04, maybe also with previous versions.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect solution, but works likewise.

In 13.10,

- Install `unity tweak tool`.
- change `launcher` background setting.
- select dark custom color for background.

dash window background also would be affected by that setting.

[image: unity tweak tool launcher setting]