# Dash background (when no blur) after upgrade

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I have a problem: I don't like the blur effect in dash, so I turned it off in ccsm. Before the upgrade, everything was ok, but now dash uses lower part of the screen as a background. It's not correct.

Take a look:

[image]

The same thing happens when I hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

When I turn on blur, its ok, but launching dash is longer (and I just dont like blur effect).

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

CCSM options for Dash:

active blur (default) -> performance issues / buggy

static blur -> a workaround to set background https://askubuntu.com/a/79286/

no blur -> currently not possible to change background, no performance issues

For easier tweaking use UnSettings http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/unsettings-a-comprehensive-tweaking-tool-for-unity