# Ghosts haunt my Unity Dash! Videos and animated images appear through the overlay!

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash

### Q1.

There's this image (*from my last Google Chrome session*) that's appearing in my Dash. There's one different image appearing in shortcut overlay (*on "press-hold" <kbd>Super</kbd> button*). This is un-intentional, so first I'd like to know **a way to remove** it. *Logging out and back in works, but that doesn't seem to solve it permanently - the problem reproduces.*

Here's a snapshot: (**ghost of facebook page**)
[image: snap1]
*(Please note the **ghost of a facebook page** within the Dash overlay area. The only window in the background is of Firefox with a **blank page**.)*

..here's **Gnost Of Nautilus**,
[image: gnostOfNautilus]

..and this is the **Ghost Of System Monitor**
[image: ghostOfSystemMonitor]

---

### Q2.

**Dash's been behaving weird** lately with videos or animations playing in the background. The video/animated-image flash through the Dash. *(The problem persists through sessions.)*

These two snaps below should explain the problem visually:

**<1>**
[image: shap2]
*(Note the youtube video is being displayed through the Dash.)*

**<2>**
[image: snap3]
*(And here's the same with a video being played with VLC.)*

How to fix that? Or is this normal, or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

just logout and login if it didn't work restart your pc, its just a glitch

Answer (score 0):

There might be a transparency thing having to do with that in settings, you might want to look at the dash settings if it continues.

If you want to change the transparency of the dash, try:

[How to change dash transparency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79272/how-to-change-dash-transparency)

You may have Static Blur on in CCSM under Unity Plugin, for the Chrome background?