# Can you remap Super-W?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I just discovered the Super-W keystroke to show all the open applications, but I find the actual keystroke inconvenient and would love to remap it (say to one of the custom keys on my Microsoft 4000 keyboard).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to remap it with CCSM. [See this answer for how to install CCSM.](https://askubuntu.com/a/62903/17739) Then look under the Scale module of the Window management section. The key command is set in the Bindings tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a new hotkey by replacing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> with whatever key combination you want, e.g. `<Primary><Shift><Super>f` would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> programmatically via the command line:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-key "'<Primary><Shift><Super>f'"
```

Another key combination of interest is the one to open all applications in all workspaces:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-all-key "'<Super>a'"
```

Comment: Leo, could you flesh out this answer a bit?  How to actually change it from [super][W] would be a nice start...  Otherwise the system will unfortunately delete your answer automatically because of low quality...

Comment: Improved! sorry, though it was self explanatory ;)

Comment: Much better...  (upvoted now)  Still not a *great answer* but better then before. **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/678348/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **:P**