# How do I hide the Unity dock?

Tags: 11.10, unity, layout

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I'm a new Ubuntu user. How to remove the menu icons in Ubuntu? I have googled and also check each System Settings but i find no options. I only use the terminal and start application from terminal - the menu icons is annoyingly ugly and I want to get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show what you want to remove - also the version of ubuntu would be useful.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the icons docked on the left. they are too annoying for the eyes. i only need the terminal to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the compiz config manager, and autohide the bar (settings are in the unity section).

Alternatively you could install and use the classic gnome desktop.
http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/09/11/install-the-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-11-10