# What personalisation software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation, personalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

What personalisation (software) would you recommend for Ubuntu 11.10? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to askubuntu.com! Since this is an international community, all questions should be asked and answered in the language of the internet - English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short list of software

[Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) - '..light-weight system monitor for X, that displays any information on your desktop.'. You can create awesome desktops with Conky.

[Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/) - 'Compiz is an OpenGL compositing manager.' You can customize your desktop with this nice piece of software.

[Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) - 'Ubuntu Tweak is an application to config Ubuntu easier for everyone.'

[Add Unity Lenses](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/10-unity-lenses-scopes/) - A list of 10 awesome lenses.

Answer (score 1):

CompizConfig Settings Manager has lots of appearance options, if this is what you are looking for.
You can find it in Ubuntu Software center.

For more technical tweaking I prefer Ubuntu Tweak. Get it from here: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Also, don't forget about the System Settings, already found on your machine: just type Settings in the Dash search bar to find it.