# Unable to change unity app icon size with ccsm

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

I was unable to change launcher icon size from ccsm, I find configure part as I followed [steps on this link](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/change-icon-size-unity-launcher.html)

But after log out / in again, the icon size didn't reduce.

I'm running Latest Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Refer this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/101415#101415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 12.04 you can do this from the appearance section of system settings.

At the bottom is a slider to change the icon size for the launcher.

[image]