# Ubuntu 12.04: Open launcher elements only with double click

Tags: 12.04, unity, usability

Sometimes I click the icons of the launcher by mistake and I have to wait until the program opens to close it again.

How to open the programs in the launcher only if I double click them?

Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity) may help. and possibly [that](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/unity-tipchange-unity-launcher-configuration-settings.html), too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launcher is not hidden I guess? I would hide the Launcher and lower the sensitivity for popping up the launcher.

And if you hit a button, hit the program that's opening and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> it's the fastest way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible before the application starts completely. You can Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> quickly as soon as it appears to close it.