# How to change the location a shortcut is linked to?

Tags: unity, shortcuts

I have 12.04, the initial user account name is **google**, then I changed the user name from **google** to **linux**. I move `/home/google` to `/home/linux`and update the `/etc/passwd` file.

But now, when I click the shortcut in unity, say, the Downloads, then give me no such `/home/google/Downloads` directory since already renamed to `/home/linux/Downloads`

I can create the `/home/google` as symbol link to `/home/linux`, it's working, but I do want to change the directory/path the Downloads shortcut point to.

So, do you know how to change the property of the shortcut?

Comment: Which shortcut are you talking about ? When you right-click on the nautilus icon in the dashboard ? And what's your version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Have you really updated your /etc/passwd file, such that it contains the new /home/linux/ location as well? Did you log out and in after the operation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the quicklists of Unity launcher, you should take a look at [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/101415#101415) and search for "quicklists".

You will have all the informations you need to edit the quicklist of nautilus, so you can change the target of the "Downloads" shortcut.