# Animations in Ubuntu 12.10 like in Ubuntu 9

Tags: 12.10, effects, animations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10. Previously I was using Ubuntu 9. This release has a nice UI makeover, but I no longer could use the awesome animations that were in Ubuntu 9.

I couldn't find the Appearance (Graphics Settings) in this version of Ubuntu, like it was there when I was using Ubuntu 9.

While dragging a window, it would drag with some effect and while pressing Alt+Tab the switching windows was also a great animation effect. Now I can't find any of these effects in Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to look up is Compiz. There is an application in the repositories called compizconfig-settings-manager (or ccsm) that has all the extra features you are looking for. Use with caution, there can be some not so nice side effects depending on your video card.