# How to customize Unity Launcher's background

Tags: unity, launcher

In this question I do not want to customize the launcher for each workspace, or change the animations or behaviors of the icons. I only want to change how the background of the Launcher looks. Let me show you what I mean:

If I do not open the Dash, the launcher looks like the following:

[image]

It looks like this because I have a background that has gray, black and white colors. So Unity tries to accommodate the launcher to contrast with it.

Now when I open the Dash, the launcher looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to make the launcher look the same as if my Dash were open (Darker, richer background). I thought maybe to invert the colors of an opened Dash with a closed one, but that the end I do not care if the colors do change when I open the Dash, so long as the darker richer version stays.

Is it possible to do this, to make the background stay with a darker color like shown in the pictures above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this out, but from the explanation given in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/101415/67346), it seems you can use `MyUnity` tweak tool to change the Launcher Background colour and transparency.

By setting the Background to a dark colour and transparency to nil, you should be able to get the desired effect.

---

As given in the post

**Launcher**

[image]

1. *color* - Launcher background color
2. *size* - Launcher icon size
3. *Transparency* - Background transparency of the launcher
4. *Show devices* - Show removable USB drives as an icon
5. *Behavior* - How the launcher interacts with windows

   - *Fixed* - The launcher will never hide.
   - *Hidden* - The launcher will hide when a window would overlay it.
6. *Display* - What effect the launcher should use when hiding i.e. to fade away or to slide (or both)
7. *Backlights* - Style of icon background

Comment: Wow yes it worked. Oddly I tried MyUnity and it did not work, I did it with CCSM using the first part you mentioned. Looks awesome.

Comment: That's odd. I tried CCSM and didn't work for me. That's why I posted MYUnity.