# How to make unity launcher apps not bundle together when you have lots of them or to speed up the bar when scrolling down to apps?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I notice  that the applications don't stay straight when you add more on. Is there a way to fix this? Can you also speed up the scrolling speed when on the unity launcher?

Comment: What are your hardware specs?

Comment: You should really mark the question as answered since this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind installing a PPA, you may consider [Drawers](https://launchpad.net/drawers). There's a nice [video by quidsup](http://youtu.be/MTwXwadnxUU) on Drawers along with installation instructions and a more recent video, also by quidsup, in which Drawers gets a mention: http://youtu.be/3jZTTp8nefw?t=4m29s at the time specified in the link. And version 13.2 has a review [here](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/drawers-132-released-active-drawers-and-new-features).

> Stack your applications under one icon with this great new Drawers feature for Unity Launcher.
>   I reckon this is one of the best new features for Unity desktop.
>
> Each Drawer can be customised with size, icon size, colour,
>   transparency, and whether to show text. Feature is available for
>   Ubuntu **12.04**, 12.10, and 13.04.
>
> Install instructions:
>
> Open Terminal
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers  
> sudo apt-get update  
> sudo apt-get install drawers
> ```

The image (stolen from quidsup's video) shows a couple of browsers stacked horizontally. (Apologies if reproducing it here is a violation in any manner.)

[image]

Caveat: I have no personal experience of Drawers.

---

As far as speeding up scrolling goes, it may be an issue of resources and may be related to the "special effects" enabled. If you have limited resources, in terms of, for example, CPU, GPU, or RAM, you could try disabling some of the visual effects associated with the Launcher. Many of them are described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity) in the section appropriate to your version.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the feature the OP wanted.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PtBfq.png) is what I thought he didn't want (see the bottom of the launcher).  I could be wrong though.

Comment: That is what I'm been looking for and use.! Thank you so much!