# Set Multiple values for StartupWMClass (to group under same launcher in Unity)

Tags: unity, 12.10, launcher, .desktop

This a specific example of a generic problem I haven't been able to find a solution for yet.

I have a program (Android Virtual Device Manager) that launches 'sub-programs' (namely emulators or virtual devices) from within itself (also can be launched from else where). I want any instances of EITHER of these programs to be grouped under the same Unity icon.

I have created a `.desktop` file to try and accomplish this but don't exactly know how to go about it. The desktop file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Android Virtual Device
Icon=/home/ben/.icons/android.svg
Exec=/home/ben/usr/bin/android avd
StartupWMClass=Android Virtual Device Manager
```

From what I understand, `StartupWMClass` is what I need to set to achieve this correctly. I have obtained the two class names ('Android Virtual Device Manager' and 'emulator64-arm') using `xprop WM_CLASS` on the repsective windows. Both work individually (the launcher icon is correctly attached to the program no matter what way it is launched), but I cannot get it to work for both.

I am assuming that I somehow need to set two values for `StartupWMClass` but have not been able to do it correctly (or know if it is a valid operation). I have tried, colon separated like environment variables, comma separated, quotes, etc and I cannot find any hints in the [official documentation](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Another, more pedantic, but probably more identifiable example is with `Matlab`. I am running 2013a and the splash screen that initially shows and the program have completely different `WM_CLASS` values. This means, when I click my launcher with `StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit` in it, the splash screen comes up with a different (default Unknown) `Unity` icon, while the rest comes up grouped under my launcher.

By using `xprop WMCLASS` and clicking on first the splash screen, then repeating with an active `Matlab` session I get the following terminal output:

```
ben@ben-OptiPlex-9010:~$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "MATLAB", "MATLAB"
ben@ben-OptiPlex-9010:~$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit"
```

If I could specify something along the lines of:

```
StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit&&MATLAB
```

That would work perfectly (as both work separately) but I have no idea of the syntax, if it even exists. I just know nothing I have tried has worked thus far.

Any help or a definitive answer either way would be great as I believe this is a pretty fundamental element of a well functioning desktop.

Comment: Would you be able to get some hints from [Drawers](http://askubuntu.com/a/244114/25656)?

Comment: I have looked at the videos of `Drawers` in that link and from what they show, it simply groups the links, when you click any sub item, it is still created with its own icon in the `Unity` launcher which is what I'm trying to stop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same problem for me with Starcraft II launched throw playonlinux. There is first a application launcher:

- `(WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Blizzard Launcher.exe", "Wine")`
  and then the game itself:
- `(WM_CLASS(STRING) = "SC2.exe", "Wine")`

I guess that wine is setting the class with the binary executable.

I had a look in bamf code (bamf_matcher.c, insert_desktop_file_class_into_table() method):

- There is a map that make the association between a desktop file and one and only one class,
- The key StartupWMClass is read with g_key_file_get_string() which is not designed to return a list of strings,
- g_key_file_get_string_list() could do that but bamf developpers did not design the framework to be able to associate multiple classes to one single desktop file.

In my case I cheat by creating 2 desktop files with same keys but StartupWMClass. This is not perfect because I still have 2 Uniy icons when in the launcher but the important thing is I know why :-).

Comment: This looks very promising, I've [asked a question](https://answers.launchpad.net/bamf/+question/228738) to try and get confirmation from them, but still no response as of yet...

Comment: This isn't quite an answer. The answer is "you can't" because the Desktop File specification makes this value a single string and not a list of strings (which is why bamfdaemon uses get_string() and not get_string_list() for that value).

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is really old, but after going through the same problem, i think i've finally created a workaround for this, and decided to share with anyone having this issue:

As we can't set multiple WMClasses for a single .desktop file, why don't set all the windows to a single WMClass?

We can do something like this (Obviously, replace `Window 1`, `Window 2` and `potatoes` with your windows names and desired WMClass):

```
xprop -name "Window 1" -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS "potatoes"

xprop -name "Window 2" -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS "potatoes"
```

And on the .desktop file we can do this: `StartupWMClass=potatoes`

Tadam! All windows are grouped now.
But hey, are we doing this manually every time the program opens up? Of course not.

We can just go and make a bash script that automagically does that every half second:

```
while true
do
    xprop -name "Window 1" -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS "potatoes"
    xprop -name "Window 2" -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS "potatoes"
    sleep 0.5
done
```

And finally, set the .sh we created to run every time the OS starts up: [image: Screenshot]

Hope my answer is helpful to anyone browsing this question.

Comment: Thank you for this answer very much. While I was looking for a bit simpler question (how to start shell script from dash _and_ group it under my launcher) your answer finally showed my the right way