# Cairo Dock problem

Tags: cairo-dock

I installed Cairo Dock but it seems like it doesn't work correctly.  The icon doesn't show correctly.

[image: Cairo Dock]

Comment: This is not related to your question but I noticed that your launcher has quite a few items and the ones at the bottom are bunched up. You may not be aware of [Drawers](https://launchpad.net/drawers), which is a neat way of organizing related items in your launcher *horizontally*. You can look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/244114/25656) of mine to get some more links.

Answer (score 0):

I think your drivers don't support the OpenGL version, so just try without (`cairo-dock -c` from the terminal).