# How do I put apps on my desktop?

Tags: 12.04

I just installed GIMP and Mumble and many other things from Synaptic and now my sidebar is getting a bit cluttered.  I want to put GIMP and other apps on my desktop not my side-bar.  I also know that I can make a shell script to run it and add a picture to it but I dont really want to do that just have the whole app on the desktop.

Comment: See the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/244114/25656. It may help you organize things so that your sidebar isn't cluttered.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/64222/47291

Answer (score 1):

Thers is a very easy way to do so for any and all programs.

Just copy the below command and paste in a new file naming somthing.sh

`gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`

Now edit properties of the file and make it executable.
And thats it you are done with your custom-desktop-launcher-maker

Now double click on the file and click on`Run in terminal` on prompt. You will be greeted with a window similar to this
[image]

Enter the command for the application you want to make a launcher in the command field. you can fill other as to your desire. You can also choose your icon. and after finishing hit `ok`. thats it!

SEE YOUR DESKTOP

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create a .desktop file. So if You wanted to put gimp on your desktop you'd do the following. As I don't know which version of Ubuntu Desktop you are using, Gnome, KDE or whatever I have made the instructions generic.

Right click on desktop and select "Create New Document", call the file something meaningful but make sure the file ends in .desktop, so logically gimp.desktop

Open up an editor and edit that file.

Paste the following text into the editor...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/gimp
Name=Gimp
Icon=/usr/share/gimp/2.0/images/gimp-logo.png
```

Save the file.

Then right click on file, select properties, and change the permission to executable in the permissions tab.

If all went well you should be able to double click that file and it will start gimp. you can also create folders on your desktop and nest your applications in those.