# How to organize many app icons?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments

I don't like to have too many launch icons in the Unity Launch bar (using Precise Ubuntu). So I put my most used app icons on the desktop. However, I'm now running out of space on the desktop. Any suggestions as to how to put the least used app icons somewhere else in order to reduce the clutter on the desktop?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/244100/25656

Answer (score 1):

Drawers (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/drawers/)
does the job well.

Comment: For before 13.04, you may be able to install free with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers` then  
`sudo apt-get update` and then  
`sudo apt-get install drawers`. You also might want to mark this question as answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can put frequent used apps on Unity Interface and well for the rest, (less frequently used apps),its a suggestion, you can install `indicator-synapse` which is alternative of Mac Spotlight.

[image]

Look at the upper left colored icon, (there you can quickly search applications) and you don’t need to clutter your desktop.

If you want to install, run this in terminal :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

Hope that helps, Let me know.

Comment: This is built into Unity. Either press the top button in the bar, or press Alt by default, type the first letters of the app you want to start, press Enter. Boom, just like spotlight.

Comment: i find indicator synapse comforting. hence