# How do I Remove/Customize Unity Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: unity, 12.10

Is there any way to remove or configure the following Unity keyboard shortcuts?

I want to make use of these keyboard shortcuts, but I have no use for what they're currently assigned to.

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Music Search)
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Application Search)
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Picture Search)

The keyboard settings utility **does not** show these anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove existing lense keyboard binding.

- To do so, open a nautilus with with root by executing `gksu nautilus`
- Navigate to `/usr/share/unity/lenses`, Now goto appropriate lenses directory .
- Inside the folder, there will be a `Shortcut` field, remove or edit as you want.

  [Source](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/how-easily-add-preferred-keyboard-shortcuts-unity-lenses)

To assign new command for these shortcut, you need to install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] and use `Commands` section at top.

More config info - [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Is this documented *anywhere*? Were you part of the Unity development team by any chance?

This works for me because I have a single-user system, but is there any way to configure this on a per-user basis? Perhaps some sort of user-space override of `/usr/share/unity/lenses` -- something in `.config` or similar?

Comment: These kinds of hidden stuff are just a mess. Why are they not available by the other keyboard bindings menus - as described in the OP??

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 the steps are different:

Open a terminal

Become root

```
sudo su -
```

The lenses are now apparently controlled by scopes

```
cd /usr/share/unity/scopes
```

The next command will show the files that contain a shortcut definition

```
grep -R "Short" *
```

Make a copy of the existing files (just in case) and verify they copied.

```
mkdir ~/scopes
cp -rp * ~/scopes
ls -Rl ~/scopes
```

Remove all the Shortcut entries  - if you would rather just disabled some of the shortcuts, then edit the specific files that returned from the previous command.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed '/Shortcut/,+1 d' {} \;
```

Verify all the shortcuts are removed

```
grep -R "Short" *
```

This takes effect immediately.  The shortcuts do not disappear from  Keyboard Shortcuts menu, however.