# How can I make Unity dock notifications more visible?

Tags: unity, notification, appearance, dock, usability

By default dock icons of applications where something is going on have a very faint glow effect. Is there any way to make them stand out more? Like jump around, have a colored arrow or something like that?

Comment: Have you taken a look here...[Configure Unity][1]?


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity