# How do I change to the desktop/layout like in the picture?

Tags: environment

I would love to change my desktop to the one below:

[image]

Could someone please help?

Comment: What version are you using? 12.04? 12.10?

Comment: I am using 12.10

Comment: As far as I can see this is the default Unity desktop on a clean install of Ubuntu with Chromium instead of Firefox as the browser. Where is your issue? Can you provide a screenshot of your **different** desktop layout?

Answer (score 1):

To run a more classic desktop we may install [gnome-session-fallback](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback) [image: Install gnome-session-fallback].

See this question on many options on how to configure the classic desktop:

- [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop)

---

**For >= 12.10** it will be like below:

We can coose at login which desktop environment we like to run:

- Click on the Ubuntu or GNOME symbol next to your login name:

  [image]
- This will open a menu with different desktop environments we can use now:

  [image]
- Choose GNOME classic for a GNOME desktop without Unity. Exemplary I added a dock ([docky](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/docky) [image: Install docky]) to show possible desktop solutions. This dock will **not be included** in the default GNOME classic desktop.

  [image]

Comment: isnt this the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop  ?

Comment: @fossfreedom yeah - I missed that on scrolling, however myunity, and Unity2D are no longer supported in 12.10. I'll make an edit to reflect this. We still dont knwo whetger the OP is really up to classic. If they are we can dupe close, fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you'll want to do following:

- Download the chromium browser, and use it.
- If you haven't already done it (it's the default). - Right-click desktop and click Change Background (Or something like it). Then select the theme called Ambiance
- The sidebar in the left, those icons, you're able to attach to the menu, by right clicking open programing, and attaching it there.

If there's any more, please comment my answer and let me know.

Comment: I meant like the whole desktop, I don't want the sidebar on the left. Just want a simple bar on top like OS X

Comment: The bar, is as far as I know, included in 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for anything bar the bar at the top, why not use Xubuntu? lightweight, clean and you have the bar on the top.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

For a closer look into Xubuntu, visit http://www.xubuntu.org/ to learn more.

Alternatively, visit http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity to see options for configuring Unity.

Good luck! :)