# Where does unity keep information on the launchers in dash?

Tags: unity, launcher

I know where the general launchers are, the ones in `/usr/share/applications` and the likes. What I'm wondering is where unity stores the launchers that are actually pinned to the side bar. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access this information using [dconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/29561#29561). Expand `com → canonical → unity → launcher` node and see the `favorites` key:

[image: favorites key]

Comment: Am I to assume then that window matching information is embedded in the .desktop files themselves?

Comment: What do you mean speaking "window matching information"? `.desktop` files generally contain command and icon, and the key is shown also keeps arrangement.

Comment: What I mean by window matching is matching a specific window being drawn to a specific icon. I've had some applications that when I pin them and use the launcher to start them, they create a new icon on the launcher instead of using the existing icon. *cough* netbeans *cough*

Comment: This means that `.desktop` files on your desktop (or where did you pick them from) have another path to the icon then those in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Ok looking at the .desktop files it seems to be stored under the "StartupWMClass" property. You can find this property by running "xprop WM_CLASS" in a terminal then click the window you're wondering about

Comment: Could one check which applications are running and then change this settings so that the ones running are always at the top of the launcher?

Comment: @Joschua there is `unity://running-apps` entry in the setting. Put it at the very beginning of the list.

Comment: @Danatela Thanks, but putting it at the very beginning didn't work out. And apparently `unity://running-apps` is already in the list..

Comment: @Joschua there should be only one entry of running apps. If the tip doesn't help, ask a new question.