# Swapping out icon set for a different one (13.10, Ambience theme)?

Tags: unity, 13.10, themes, icons

I have hunted for an answer to this one, which must be out there, but I only seem to find older, out-dated "solutions".

I would like to use the new [Lubuntu Box Icon set](http://lubuntublog.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/box-044.html) in Ubuntu 13.10. **But how??**

My set-up at the moment is *almost* standard ... other than using Nitrogen to manage a dual-screen display, and the [patched Nemo](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) which requires me to do this:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

Many thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that what I need is the [Unity Tweak Tool](https://askubuntu.com/a/294604/38585).

It's a very simple matter once you find the right tool for the job!

[image: unity-tweak-tool]