# Unity Launcher "application start" feedback in custom theme

Tags: unity, launcher, themes

When I start application in Unity, the application launcher icon blinks informing me that something is happening. That's a behaviour in default Unity theme.

However, in theme I use (Moka) such functionality is turned off and looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLVGw.jpg

There is no feedback from Unity that application is starting. Is there any way to bring it back without screwing up this theme?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an indirect answer, but you can try changing unity settings where it defines launch animation (I'm not sure how will it react with *Moka* theme)

Please check this answer for configuring unity:
https://askubuntu.com/a/294604/14356

The part that you're looking for is on setting "Launching animation" to "Pulse"

On the other hand, if it screws the theme, you should address it towards the creators of *Moka* theme.

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't affect Moka.

Comment: So, changing the Launching animation to any other option didn't affect anything at all?

Comment: Yep. I'm wondering how this functionality gets turned off, so maybe I could revert it in Moka by editing some config files. Not sure where to look for info about it.

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/moka-project/moka-gtk-theme) the official repository for *Moka gtk theme*. I have filed an issue there, hope to hear from them soon.