# What are some handy run commands?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I have been using Windows systems for a few years now, and most of my tasks used to get accomplished without using the mouse. I have recently switched to Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm eager to know the keyboard shortcuts. I have some confusions as well.

1. I use this combo `Alt+F2` to go to my home folders `\home\` etc. Is there any way out? I used to do the same using winkey+R in Windows.
2. I will be using Google Chrome, TexMaker and LibreOffice only. I would love to know if there are quicker ways to launch these apps, other than going to the launch bar and clicking their icons. For Chrome, I do this `google-chrome` in the terminal. It was way easier in Windows though; just winkey+R and then `chrome`.
3. When I'm using chrome, if I press `Alt` then there's this *Type your command* bar pops up on top of my screen. What's that?

If someone can give me a handy document where all the shortcuts are placed, I'll be glad. Thanks!

Comment: "Is there any way out?" not sure what that means? Do you want to exit the dialog?

Comment: I believe that link will do. Also, thanks for the edit. I didn't know that such greetings are not welcome on the platform. By _another way out_ I mean any shortcut shorter than this. Any thoughts on `3.` ?@muru

Comment: To change the shortcut, probably unity-tweak-tool has an option: http://askubuntu.com/a/294604/158442. For 3, IIRC you can  access the menu entries by typing in that bar (for example, if File menu contains Save As, type "Save As", and so on)

Comment: @muru If I type `cd Documents` and then type `nautilus`, it seems to open the home directory, instead of opening the documents folder. What am  doing wrong?

Comment: If you're doing that in the Alt-F2 prompt, each command is executed individually. Just do `nautilus Documents`