# How to remap Super + w to a different keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, window

How can I remap the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> shortcut, which spreads all the windows, to one of the function keys?

Comment: Probably unity-tweak-tool has an option: http://askubuntu.com/a/294604/158442

Answer (score 1):

This works on 14.04:

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Run CCSM from the Dash.
3. Go to **Window management** -> **Scale** -> **Bindings** tab -> 
   **Initiate Window Picker**
4. Click the keyboard shortcut (`<Super>w` on your PC, but `<Super>Tab` in this screenshot).

   [image: CCSM - Window management - Scale]
5. Click **Grab key combination**, press the desired key(s), then click OK.

   [image: Edit Initiate Window Picker]

   I chose `<Super>Tab` to be like Windows 10.

Comment: I've had no success with Compiz on Ubuntu 20.