# How to have a way to quickly change programs in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher

I just have Unity running today, I like the way it hides stuff to increase screen space. Also, I like the new Workspace switcher and Applications "app". But I now find it hard to switch apps. Alt tab seems slower than click if I have more than afew tabs running

Can I somehow lock the "dock", maybe at the bottom, and make it smaller, something like Windows 7 taskbar?

*I hope this is not a duplicate, I tried searching, but may have searched for the wrong terms, since I am new to Ubuntu*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You [currently can't move the Launcher][1] but you can fix it in place and make it smaller.

- [How to resize the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18345/how-do-i-resize-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: whats the super key?

Comment: [What are the meta, super, and hyper keys?](http://askubuntu.com/q/19558/667)

Answer (score 2):

With Compiz, you can configure many ways for quickly change programs. You can make shortcuts to change programs at the Workspace in focus or at All Workspaces. You can define how fast you want it to work.

Remember to go to Misc Options to set the speed you want:

[image]

**What I like most is "Swing Switcher":**

[image]

---

**"Swift Switcher" is beautiful:**

[image]

---

**"Static Application Switcher" is simple but very useful:**

[image]

---

**And there is the "normal" application Switcher:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You currently cannot move the Unity <s>Dock</s> Launcher ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/q/33605/8570)) but you can alter the hide behaviour and icons size with the **Unity Plugin**  using:

[CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install CompizConfig Settings Manager]

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```