# How do I shrink the Unity launcher icons to make them smaller?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resize the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18345/how-do-i-resize-the-unity-launcher)

I would like to make the icons in the launcher smaller, so that more of them can be displayed in that precious vertical space.

How is this possible?