# Custom configuration settings for Unity launcher in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04

Although I liked the Unity interface of Ubuntu 11.04, I find that few aspects of it are really annoying, like the unnecessary mouse over effect caused when the mouse pointer lingers around the top left corner near the menu bar.

Is there a way to configure the default settings of the Unity launcher? I would like to disable the mouse over effect. If possible I would rather prefer it to be set to always-visible-on-the-screen mode.

Adding to this, I use a 14 inch laptop, one or two windows when opened really clutter the unity launcher icons. I need to scroll down the launcher icons often to view stuff. Is it possible to change the size of the default icons on the unity interface so that more items can be fit into it?

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve these two things.

Thanks

Veekay

Comment: Can you split this up into two questions please? I am pretty sure these are duplicates

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launcher icons size can be changed if you have compiz config installed. Then open Unity plugin and on the tab there is a slider to set icons size. See this:

[Launcher Icons Size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39550/how-do-i-shrink-the-unity-launcher-icons-to-make-them-smaller)

Regarding other question please see this:

[Configure Unity launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)