# how do I make the unity launcher icons smaller

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I shrink the Unity launcher icons to make them smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39550/how-do-i-shrink-the-unity-launcher-icons-to-make-them-smaller)

I'm looking for a way to make my desktop icons (Unity launchbar) smaller. I installed ccsm and then tried Alt/F2 and entered "about config". However, when I enter "about config", a purple Unity icon comes up, but when I click on it, nothing happens.