# How to resize Unity Launcher Icons?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resize the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18345/how-do-i-resize-the-unity-launcher)

Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to resize the icons in the launcher. As shown in this picture there is a resize tab and a restore defaults button:

[image]
But I don't have it. It's the same but without the 'Restore Defaults' and the 'Launcher Icon Size'. How do I enable those buttons or if I can't, how do I change the size of the icons?

Comment: Installing myunity is probably the only way you'll be able to do this without upgrading. Marking it as a duplicate so we can merge these into one question!